# MFC and Diagramming libraries/ vector graphics?

Tags: graphics, mfc

Can you recommend good diagramming libraries?

I wish to draw vector graphics and make custom shapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lacking a particular reason to do something else, you typically use MFC itself -- `CDC::Polyline`, `CDC::PolyPolyline`, `CDC::Arc`, `CDC::PolyBezier`, etc.

Edit: I'm afraid if you want a complete example of a vector drawing program, complete with scaling, editing, saving and opening files, and such, you're probably in the wrong place. I (along with quite a few others here) can and often will answer reasonably specific questions, but if you want examples of relatively large, elaborate programs, some place like [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com) is probably a better bet. I'm not sure they have one, but at least there you'd stand a reasonable chance. About the closest I can advise where would be to the look at the standard Scribble tutorial. It certainly uses vector drawing, and supports saving and loading files. I'm not sure, but I seem to recall it supporting scaling as well.

Comment: need a fuller example where you can load/save, resize and manipulate shapes like a vector-graphics editor